# Sql запрос INSERT/UPDATE с использованием htmlspecialcharse

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

Есть супер-проблема ))

```
//PHP код. Ловим все что в POST
$post_all = $_POST;
//смотрим для какой таблицы предназначены записи, грохаем пару переменных, оставляем только данные

//ключи массива - названия полей в таблицах
$post_key = array_keys($post_all);

//вносим данные в бд
$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$table."` (`".implode('`,`',$post_key)."`) VALUES ('".implode('\',\'',$post_all)."')";
```

Собственно все супер, в HTML формах все прописал - и запросы отдельно каждый INSERT/UPDATE не надо писать. .. Только вот от sql-инекций теперь не защищен. Может кто объяснить, как быть? В implode htmlspecialchars не добавить

Comment: заносить в отдельный массив и защищать. по-другому как-то не торт

Comment: эмм.. ну сейчас же столько всего напридумывали, что бы усложнить жизнь программиста... ооп, mvc, я даже сейчас на PDO буду переходить ( http://hashcode.ru/questions/246758/php-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-mysql )

неужели нельзя как то добавить данные в таблицу заранее все 'обезвредив' . implode использую т.к. не знаю сколько на самом деле полей. Так удобнее, если бы не инекции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($post_all as $key => $value) {
       $post_all[$key] = "`".addslashes($value)."`"; // htmlspecialcharse что угодно вам
}
```

Answer (score 0):

возможно не htmlspecialcharse, а htmlspecialchars ? (без буквы **е**)

Comment: опечатка. исправил